# Why OpenFileDialog requires Microsoft.Win32?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I program in C# WPF. In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), it states that `OpenFileDialog` belongs to namespace **System.Windows.Controls**. But simply having using **System.Windows.Controls** does not allow me to use `OpenFileDialog`. I have to add using **Microsoft.Win32** as well to use OpenFileDialog.

Why?

Comment: Are you thinking of the [SilverLight 4 OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) vs the [WPF OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is just a *Silverlight* documentation error/limitation.

This *.Net* [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) link correctly places the OpenFileDialog in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace.